# Java operations in Swing thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety

I have a problem.
Here is the code:

```
JButton buttonChangeServer = new JButton("Change server");
    buttonChangeServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getLobbies();
            }
        }
    });

private void getLobbies() {
    lobbyListModel.removeAllElements();
    statusLabel.setText("Connecting...");
    final ArrayList<LobbyInfo> lobbyInfos = 
            UserClient.getLobbies(host, action, null);
    if (lobbyInfos != null) {
        setLobbies(lobbyInfos);
        statusLabel.setText("Sucessfully got lobby list from " + getHost());
    }
    else {
        statusLabel.setText("Failed to connect to " + getHost());
    }
}
```

The `UserClient.getLobbies(host, action, null)` method executes for a 3 seconds (timeout) if it can not establish connection.
The problem is that this two operations

```
lobbyListModel.removeAllElements();
statusLabel.setText("Connecting...");
```

are not visible while executing.

I suppose that the problem is that the method `getLobbies()` in `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` executes in Swing thread, and all the GUI operations are not being shown till the end of the execution of the `getLobbies();`

My aim is to show all the changes of GUI, before and after the execution of `UserClient.getLobbies(host, action, null);`. How can I manage that? Is there an easy way to show all of them? Thank you.

**P.S.** One of the solutions may be putting that potentionally long operation in another thread, like this:

```
private void getLobbies() {
        lobbyListModel.removeAllElements();
        statusLabel.setText("Connecting...");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final ArrayList<LobbyInfo> lobbyInfos = 
                    UserClient.getLobbies(host, action, null);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (lobbyInfos != null) {
                            setLobbies(lobbyInfos);
                            statusLabel.setText("Sucessfully got lobby list from " + getHost());
                        }
                        else {
                            statusLabel.setText("Failed to connect to " + getHost());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

It works, but it is rather complicated. Are there any ways easier?

Comment: SwingWorker is not hard -- I suggest studying that.

Answer (score 4):

> One of the solutions may be putting that potentially long operation in another thread

Yes, long operations (or blocking operations) should not execute on the EDT.

So you do need to execute the long running task on a separated Thread. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Worker Threads and Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for the Swing solution to this problem.

When your query finishes executing you can "publish" the results so the code is executed on the EDT when the Swing components are updated.