# Swing - revalidate of UI not happening

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, repaint, event-dispatch-thread

I have a `JButton` and a `JLabel`. The code is written so that when the user clicks on the button, the action performed changes the text of the `JLabel` and starts doing some stuff. However, in reality, Label text doesn't change until the stuff being done is finished.

This is the code in the button action

```
lbl.setText("Doing");
revalidate();
DoStuff();
```

The label's text doesn't change until the method `DoStuff` returns. I know `revalidate` just schedules a call to `paint` so I think that this is because the paint thread never gets a slice to change the text.

How do I fix this?

Here is a repro program. Instead of `DoStuff()`, I have a `while(true);` which simulates the same behaviour. If you run this program, you will have to kill it to get it to exit.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Util1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Util1();
    }

    public Util1()
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ExamplePane());

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true); 
            }
        });
    }


    protected class ExamplePane extends JPanel 
    {
        public ExamplePane() 
        {
            final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            JButton btn = new JButton("Do Stuff");
            final JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Status");
            add(btn);
            add(lbl);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {
                    lbl.setText("Doing");
                    revalidate();
                    while(true);
                }
            });

        }            
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, that actions in `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` method execute in Swing thread. The changes are not shown till all of actions are executed. You can, for example, perform your `doStaff` method in another thread.
For more details, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064902/java-operations-in-swing-thread). I had the same problem.